# Probability of choosing coins from a bag (why doesn't binomial coefficient work?)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

Studying for my exam and would appreciate some help. I have a bag with 2 pennies, 1 nickel and 1 dime. I pick 2 at random.

The solutions say:

Pr(PP) = $\frac{2}{4} \times \frac{1}{3}$ = $\frac{1}{{4 \choose 2}}$ = $\frac{1}{6}$

Pr(ND) = $\frac{1}{4} \times \frac{1}{3}$ = $\frac{1}{12}$

Why can't we have the probability of Pr(ND) = $\frac{1}{{4 \choose 1}}$? It doesn't produce the right answer in this case, but it did for 2 pennies. Why is this? Is it possible to use binomial coefficient for {N,D}?

Comment: Why do you think Pr(ND)=1/$\binom{4}{1}$?

Comment: Your question seems to depend upon the order in which you choose the coins. You should make this clear. The probability of getting one nickel and one dime when you pick two coins is 1/6. The probability of drawing a nickle *and then* a dime is 1/12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pr(ND) = $\frac{1}{4\choose1}$ is implying that the probability of choosing a nickel then a dime is $\frac{1}{4}$. For the first one, with the choosing of 2 pennies, it's 4 choose 2 becuase there are a total of 4 coins, and 2 of them are pennies, so the probability of choosing 2 pennies is $\frac{1}{4\choose2}$

For choosing a dime then a nickel, think about how many coins you have. You have 4 coins, and one is a nickel and one is a dime. The probability of choosing the nickel is $\frac{1}{4}$ and the probability of choosing the dime is $\frac{1}{3}$ (becaue you've already chosen the nickel, so you now have 3 coins to choose from). this results in a vlue of $\frac{1}{12}$. Similarly you can do P(N) = $\frac{1}{4\choose1}$ and P(D) = $\frac{1}{3\choose1}$, so P(N and D) = P(N) * P(D) = $\frac{1}{4\choose1}$ * $\frac{1}{3\choose1}$ = $\frac{1}{12}$

Answer (score 1):

The confusion comes from the apparently similar formula for Pr(PP) ($\frac{1}{{4 \choose 2}}$). This formula uses the fact that you choose two items (both P coins) among four coins. The $2$ comes from that you choose two coins, not that you have two ways to obtain them.

If the case of Pr(ND), you choose one N coin ($\frac{1}{{4 \choose 1}}$)  and then one D coin ($\frac{1}{{3 \choose 1}}$) which gives $\frac{1}{12}$.

Comment: I understood perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Mirroring the case of $DD$, you may want to write
$$ Pr(ND) = \frac{1}{{4 \choose 1}} \cdot \frac{1}{{3 \choose 1}} $$
Because first you choose $1$ out of $4$, and then $1$ out of $3$.

Your $\frac{1}{{4 \choose 1}}$ alone is the probability to pick a nikel (or equivalently a dime).

Comment: Makes perfect sense, thank you!